# Почему не показывается моя статистика в github?

Tags: git, github, статистика

Создал репозиторий и начал делать свой проект. По итогу сейчас моя статистика гита все белые квадраты. Хотя у меня 60 коммитов. Это как-то можно исправить и сделать все зеленым?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

График активности профиля - это отметки о записях [`contributions`](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/viewing-contributions-on-your-profile), сделанных в репозиториях, сюда входят не только коммиты. Записи учитываются только если они соответствуют определенным критериям.

Учитываются [`issue`](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/creating-an-issue) и [`pull request`](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request), если они открыты в отдельном репозитории, а не в ответвлении [`fork`](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo).

Коммиты учитываются в графике активности если выполнены следующие условия:

- Адрес электронной почты, указанный в коммите, привязан к вашему аккаунту.
- Коммит был сделан в отдельный репозиторий, а не в ответвление [`fork`](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo).
- Коммит был сделан в основную ветку (обычно `master`) или в ветку `gh-pages` (для репозиториев с подключёнными [github pages](https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages)).

Дополнительно, хотя бы одно из перечисленного должно быть верно:

- Вы владелец этого репозитория или [`collaborator`](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-security-vulnerabilities/adding-a-collaborator-to-a-security-advisory), или вы являетесь сотрудником [`member`](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/inviting-users-to-join-your-organization) организации-владельца репозитория или [`outside collaborator`](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/adding-outside-collaborators-to-repositories-in-your-organization).
- Вы сделали ответвление [`fork`](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo) репозитория.
- Вы открыли [`pull request`](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request) или [`issue`](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/creating-an-issue) в этом репозитории.
- Вы добавили репозиторий в избранное (отметили звездочкой).

---

Подробнее см. [Why are my contributions not showing up on my profile?](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile)

Answer (score 3):

Статистика отображается только для публичных репозиториев. Активность в приватных репозиториях настраивается отдельно:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9ytV.png]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Include private contributions on my profile]

Надо выбрать: **[v] Include private contributions on my profile**

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык